# Using Windows git.exe with Magit on WSL2 Hangs on commit

Tags: magit, emacsclient, terminal-emacs, wsl

I currenlty run `emacs-nox` on `WSL2`. My workflow is as such:

`[Gentoo Linux Host]` –ssh–> `[WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Windows VM)]` –open–> `[emacs]` –edit–> `/mnt/c/<Path>/<Files>`

There is a significant performance increase to using the windows `git.exe` instead of the one on Ubuntu in wsl as I am working primarily in `/mnt/c/<Path>/<Files>`

I setup `magit-git-executable` to use windows `git.exe` as follows:

```lisp
(when (string-match "-[Mm]icrosoft" operating-system-release)
  (setq magit-git-executable "/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe"))
```

It works great; however, the only thing I cannot seem to get working is `magit-commit`

I did manage to get it working without emacs however.

I created a script in wsl to convert the git.exe path argument to a wsl path

`/usr/bin/wslemacs`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
WSL_PATH=$(wslpath -u "$1")
emacsclient "$WSL_PATH"
```

I then copied the command that `magit-commit` runs by grabbing it from `M-x list-process` in emacs and added `-c "core.editor=wsl -e wslemacs"`.

```sh
git.exe --no-pager ... -c "core.editor=wsl -e wslemacs" commit --
```

When run from `cmd.exe` on windows it successfully opens `COMMIT_EDITMSG` in emacs running on wsl just as magit would.

I tried adding this to `magit-git-global-arguments` but still no luck.

I tried writing some output to a file from my `wslemacs` script to see if it was even being called when using magit-commit and it doesn't seem to be.

I tried using full paths to wsl and to my wslemacs script and still nothing works.

I was looking into `magit-git.el` and notice some stuff like `magit-cygwin-mount-points` that perhaps are hinting that something similar must be handled for wsl? I am really not sure.

What occurs when I try to commit in emacs with magit is it spawns a process to `git.exe` and it seems to just hang forever.

I tried looking at the `with-editor-debug` output but nothing jumps out at me. Happy to post if anyone thinks it would be helpful.

The only other thing I notice is that I think `with-editor` runs a separate emacs server than the one I was able to successfully commit when running `git.exe` directly from `cmd.exe`

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** I did a bit more digging. looks like this is the value of `process-environment` in the `magit-start-process` function in `magit-process.el`

```shell
"ALTERNATE_EDITOR=sh -c 'printf \"\\nWITH-EDITOR: $$ OPEN $0\\037 IN $(pwd)\\n\"; sleep 604800 & sleep=$!; trap \"kill $sleep; exit 0\" USR1; trap \"kill $sleep; exit 1\" USR2; wait $sleep'" "GIT_EDITOR=/usr/bin/emacsclient28 --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server"
"LC_ALL"
"_=/usr/bin/emacs"
"OLDPWD=/mnt/c/TFSApps"
"SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0"
"MSSQL_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=True"
"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dev/kotlinc/bin:/home/dev/.local/bin:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"
"XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"
"SSH_CLIENT=172.24.64.1 1685 2222"
"GIT_EDITOR=wsl -e wslemacs"
"SHLVL=1"
"LPASS_AGENT_TIMEOUT=43200"
"USER=dev"
"LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"
"TERM=dumb"
"LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s"
"SSH_CONNECTION=172.24.64.1 1685 172.24.66.118 2222"
"LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:"
"LANG=C.UTF-8"
"HOME=/home/dev"
"MOTD_SHOWN=pam"
"SCREENDIR=/home/dev/.screen"
"LOGNAME=dev"
"PWD=/mnt/c/TFSApps/Common/ORIFC/ORIFCXX"
"EDITOR=wsl -e wslemacs"
"JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"
"SHELL=/bin/bash"
```